# Issue with "runtime" keyword on JSON request through APIM

Tags: c#, json, azure, rest, apim

I'm having trouble trying to receive a request through Azure APIM. The problem only happends when I send a JSON body with the word "**runtime**" in it, for example:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "company_name": "runtime something"
}
```

I've traced the requests and when it tries to reach the API backend something happens and the entire API backend restarts. The request doesn't reach the backend.
I think that it is a security measure from the Azure/APIM part, but I'm not sure.

The thing is: we have to receive this "**runtime**" string as it is part of a client's company name.

Strange thing is that it only happens in APIM. If we try to send the same JSON through the backend's IP, it works.

We found a workaround but it's not what we want to do for every endpoint. Instead of asking for a class with all the required fields, we ask for a generic object and then, inside the controller, we try to convert it to the class we were expecting before.

The backend is in C# and runs on an Azure container.

Can someone help us?

Thanks

Comment: do you have any logs from the Azure API Management that you can disclose?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Http Triggered function and imported to APIM.

This function expects a parameter either in request body or as a query parameter.

I am testing the function in APIM as shown below-

[image]
[image]

> The request doesn't reach the backend. I think that it is a security measure from the Azure/APIM part, but I'm not sure.

Here I am passing name as `runtime something` and got expected result. AFAIK, APIM is not blocking `runtime` keyword.

Comment: I've checked that the client succesfully sent a request to another endpoint, different use-case.
On the same project I can't receive the "runtime" keyword on an endpoint, but in another it works. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: @Brunno You can either create a fresh APIM instance or you can raise it with the product team.